# Cannot run Postgres Stored Procedure

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a very simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delivery.get_assets(IN row_limit integer) 
AS $$
BEGIN
    select group_id 
    from delivery.assets
    order by id desc 
    limit row_limit;
END ;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql ;
```

I'm trying to run the SP using:

```
CALL delivery.get_assets(6)
```

The error I get is as follows:

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data HINT:  If you want to
>   discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead. CONTEXT: 
>   PL/pgSQL function delivery.get_assets(integer) line 3 at SQL statement
>   SQL state: 42601

I'm using PostgresQL 11.

In SQL Server all I have to do is call the SP.  I read that in Postgres, you don't need a return statement as you would with functions.  Any help is appreciated!

***AS PER COMMENTS BELOW, I'VE CHANGED THE SP TO A FUNCTION (Thank you JSpratt & Horse With No Name).

I'm almost there, but now when I call the function, it's returning in the following format:

[image: returned data]

How do I get this to return as a normal data set in a grid?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION delivery.get_assets(
    number_rows integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(assets_media_id INT, assets_person_id INT) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
 RETURN QUERY SELECT
 media_id,
 person_id  
 FROM delivery.assets;

END; $BODY$;
```

Comment: Use `PERFORM` instead of `SELECT` in your query. Why have a procedure to select something without returning the results though? If you want the results you need to add `RETURNS <something>` where <something> is a `TABLE` or the type of `group_id` and add `RETURNS QUERY` above your query.

Comment: The `RETURNS` statement is added before `AS $$`. What you're trying to do is actually a `FUNCTION`.

Comment: @JSpratt:  I'm working off of this document:  https://severalnines.com/blog/overview-new-stored-procedures-postgresql-11  It looks like you don't have to return anything - that the SP does that on its own.  To your second point.  I tried adding the Return before AS $$ and it didn't work.

Comment: OK... I think I misunderstood.  SP's don't return anything.  So they're more for Inserts and updates?

Comment: If you want to return a result, use a set returning function not a procedure. If you don't want to return anything, you need to store the result somewhere.

Comment: There is no need for PL/pgSQL to wrap a simple SELECT statement. A `language sql` would be much more efficient

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. I've tried using the SQL language, but I get the following error:  "ERROR:  syntax error at or near "RETURN".  LINE 16:  RETURN QUERY SELECT".  I'm coming from SQL Server where creating functions/stored procedures seems to be a bit more straightforward. I appreciate the help!

Comment: `return` is a PL/pgSQL statement. See here for an SQL example: https://rextester.com/WRIW16688